# private network with single IP multiple servers

Tags: linux, networking, subnet, forwarding, gateway

I am trying to set up a subnet in our company.

We got several (10+) Linux servers for computing but we can only get 1 static IP (company policy, 10.x.x.x address).
So the idea is to place a *routing device* in between the network and our servers that gets the only static IP.

Now the only way to my knowledge is that port forwarding can be used to redirect the traffic to the correct server.

While most people are not familiar with Linux, it should be easy that all servers can be accessed at default port 22 (SSH).

In what way can this be arranged?

Worst case solution is to use a VPN but that requires extra software to be installed on each client.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you mean that you only have one _public_ IP address?

Comment: Please say what kind of addresses are available for you to assign to your 10+ linux servers. Private (RFC1918) addresses? Dynamically-assigned addresses? IPv6 addresses?

Comment: I'm talking about private 10.x.x.x network addresses. Only 1 is static available for me but I have more that 1 host.

Comment: Wait a minute.. you only have one _private_ address and 10 machines? Go find whoever runs your network and beat some sense into him.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 3 network layers. No, there is no way to implement DNS for port traffic redirections.

DNS is just alternative name for IP address, and to make a connection you need both IP and port. Since you only have 1 viable IP address, you only have 1 port 22. There are no such things as "virtual hosts" on layers 3 & 4.

You basically have 2 options here. First one is to have 10 different ports, and port forward them to backend servers. For example, port forward :10122 to server1:22, :10222 to server2:22, etc.

Other options - which you correctly assumed is better - is to set up VPN. But it requires additional services which you must maintain so it's a trade off situation.